# lambda expressions are not supported at this language level IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, javafx, ide

I'm trying to create my first fxml java project and at the initialising stage I'm trying to set cell value factory for the table columnt, for example

```
      @FXML
        private void initialize() {
        agentId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getIdProperty());
       .....}
```

and this is underlined red and gives an error that mentioned in title. Changing language level in project structure gives no effect. What else may be the reason of error?

**UPD:** I've found that it is nesessary to install java with lambdas that is not included to the official release. I did it and nevertheless it didn't help. I've downloaded it [here](http://download.java.net/lambda/b106/windows-x64/lambda-8-b106-windows-x64-02_sep_2013.zip)

Comment: I assume you are setting the language level to 1.8?

Comment: @James_D it is not written that it is 1.8, but 8

Comment: Have you tried using Android N sdk with Jack compiler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the answer is the following: I had to change the language level not only in project structure->project but in project structure-> modules too.

Comment: This fixed my problem too.  But it's not just lamdas - it's all higher-level language changes.  I set my modules to use project default, which defers to the top-level.

Answer (score 24):

I had to do a few things to get rid of this problem.

1. File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK: Change it to Java 1.8.XX
2. File > Project Structure > Project > Language Level: SDK 8 (in my case SDK default was already 8)
3. File > Project Structure > Modules > Sources > SDK 8 (in my case SDK default was already 8)
4. File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Project bytecode version > 1.8
5. File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Per-module bytecode version > Target bytecode version > 1.8

That should do the trick.

Comment: There is no java compiler option in Compiler tab.. please help

Answer (score 5):

If you are use Android Studio version 3.2.1 ,you can change the language level using below mention steps:

1. Go to project structure
2. Under modules section,click on app.
3. In the properties tab, change the Source Compatibility to 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on *File*, left top corner in Android Studio.
2. Click on *Project structure*.
3. Click on *App*.
4. Choose *Properties* and set *Source Compatibility* to **1.8**.

Answer (score 2):

For "Android Studio" version 3.3:

1. Click on "File" (left top corner in "Android Studio").
2. Click on "Project structure".
3. Click on "App" (under "Modules").
4. In the "Properties" tab, change "Source Compatibility" value to "1.8".
5. In the "Properties" tab, change "Target Compatibility" value to "1.8".

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been through the above and it's still not fixed it, and if you are setting up a new module, check your module source folder hasn't been added to the parent module. I found it was being compiled at 1.5 as this was the parent module setting (since the parent contained no java source). Updating that to 1.8 too finally got rid of the warning and removing the module's source folder from the parent module.
File > Project Structure > Modules (parent of module) > Sources > Language level

Answer (score -1):

Please try to change below value (it worked for me),

- File > Project Structure > Project > Project language level = "8 -
  Lambdas, type annotations etc."
- File > Project Structure > Modules > Language Level = "8 - Lambdas,
  type annotations etc."

Comment: Project language level isn't an option in Project. it's either Android Gradle Plugin version or Gradle version.

Comment: It also isn't an option in Modules either.

Comment: Could you please check out your IntelliJ version, above is based on unlimited 2020.2